# Touchscreen HP 520 1085uk Overheating

Tags: cooling, overheating

I don't know if my Processor Power Management is set correctly. I need a cooler pc, not a quick one.

My screen keeps going off when I watch a video, Youtube or generally when I've been surfing on Chrome for a few hours. Is it the PPM set incorrectly? It is a home PC, always plugged therefore, Min set 25% Max 75% and System Cooling Policy Active.

Can anyone help as to why the screen goes off, it feels warm at the back, very warm.

Comment: When the screen goes off does the computer continue working, can you still hear the audio? It might sound silly but is the PC in a place where it receives direct sunlight?